# Pymodbus adding float to server context register

Tags: python, modbus

I'm new to pymodbus and modbus in general, I've been trying for some time now to add a float directly
to server context without any success, I wondered if you had any lead on how to do it. I already try to use payload by doing something like :

```
builder = BinaryPayloadBuilder(endian=Endian.Little)
builder.add_32bit_float(long(69000))
payload = builder.build()

context[slave_id].setValues(register, address, payload)
```

However I get an error about pymodbus trying to cast the payload to int, my code is mostly the one from the sync server example.
Any help would be very nice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
builder = BinaryPayloadBuilder(endian=Endian.Little)
builder.add_32bit_float(30.3)
payload = builder.to_registers()

context[slave_id].setValues(register, address, payload)
```

This is the correct way, take note that "register" is the starting registers and all modbus registers are 16 bit wide so a 32 bit float occupies 2 (register and register+1).

Answer (score 1):

After some research on register and and splitting of float into 16bit integer I came up with :

```
register = 3
slave_id = 0x00
address  = 0x01

values   = context[slave_id].getValues(register, address, count=2)

# Two integers to a floating point
i1 = values[0]
i2 = values[1]
f = unpack('l',pack('<HH',i1,i2))[0]
f = f+1
# Floating point to two integers
i1, i2 = unpack('<HH',pack('l',f))
print(f,i1,i2)

context[slave_id].setValues(register, address, [i1,i2])
```

I had some issue with the encoding in Endian check what is the one you need with your modbus client,